# Is It Possible to Create Read/Write Dependency?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Just curious if it's possible to create a read/write (2 way) external dependency using svn:externals.  I noticed that any time I create new files within the folders that belong to the external repos and add/commit them I get the following error:

```
svn: E155005: No write-lock in '/PATH/TO/DIR'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to operate on the externals directory just as any other working copy.

I wonder how you setup your externals? Maybe this will help: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

Usually these errors are problems in the working copies.  Are you trying to commit the file from your root or from the directory of the external?